# How do I send an Email using c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a Windows Form that sends an email when the user clicks a button, but every time I try, an exception is being raised: Failure sending mail. What is wrong with my code?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        NetworkCredential basicCredential =
            new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("myemailadress@gmail.com");

        smtpClient.Host = "smpt.gmail.com";
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

        message.From = fromAddress;
        message.Subject = "your subject";
        //Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.Body = "<h1>your message body</h1>";
        message.To.Add("towhomisend@yahoo.com");

        try
        {
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Error, could not send the message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the full exception message?

Comment: Are `"username", "password"` correct credentials to myemailadress@gmail.com ?

Comment: Not reproducible. Please post correct account, user name, and password. :-)

Comment: a) You've mistyped smtp in smtp.gmail.com b) AFAIK, you have to use SSL with Google on port 587.

Comment: I made the changes, but still: Failure sending mail... Any other ideas why it's not working?

Answer (score 6):

use `"smtp.gmail.com"` instead of `"smpt.gmail.com"`

Comment: i think he meant: "smtp.gmail.com" instead of "smpt.gmail.com" as it is in the OP

Comment: yes saw the difference right now, +1 and deleted my wrong comment.

Answer (score 2):

1) Check whether SMTP settings are correct and server is configured correctly (Host & Port Settings)

2)Check whether credentials(user name and password) are correct

3)Check whether firewall is blocking the request

4).Check port 587 If it is blocked in firewall

Port 587: 
This is the default mail submission port. When a mail client or server is submitting an email to be routed by a proper mail server, it should always use this port.

Comment: The username and password from my Gmail account?

Answer (score 2):

The 'smtpClient.Host = "smpt.gmail.com";' part is incorrect.

Change "smpt.gmail.com" to "smtp.gmail.com"

"S M T P" - not - "S M P T"

Comment: So you're saying it isn't simple mail protocol transfer ? :) +1

Comment: @john That is indeed what I am saying. It is "Simple Mail Transfer Protocol" instead. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use `"smtp.gmail.com" instead of "smpt.gmail.com"`

That aside 
Confirm one more thing, You have to enable email from other program in your gmail. 
When you try to send once, you will get a notification in you email ID.
You have to enable it there.